# displaying data from database into my blade page

Tags: html, laravel

i have 2 tables in my database one for student payments and the other for professor salary/payments, i want to display both of them in a 2 tables in my view !!

[this is the payment controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SzgU.png)

i am not having any problem on retrieving professor payment but i couldn't retrieve student payment to display it on my view 
[my view page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NRzX.png)

this is my blade page where i wanna display student payment [where i wanna display student payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtFWN.png)

any suggestion ?

Comment: Instead of images you should consider uploading you code here and expected output.

Comment: @Mohamed add a relation in student payment model

Comment: @Mohamed Midou, Why your <td> is empty ?

Comment: @danish-khan-I there's no error output it's just not retrieving the values from database

Comment: @Ulaganathan there's a relation between the models

Comment: @VideshChauhan because when i add this
 <th scope="row">{{$payment->id}}</th>
it retrieve the professor payment id not the student

Comment: @Mohamed
You have assigned $payment for professor and $payment_s for student.
try  like my  below  answer

Comment: @Ulaganathan i am sorry i am new to stack overflow i didn't know how to answer the right question if u don't mind i will repeat for you ?

Comment: @MohamedMidou please post here

Comment: @Ulaganathan i didn't know how to explain to you my situation :/

Comment: @mohamed what is the issue? what are you trying to do?.Post these details

Comment: @Ulaganathan can i have your email to contact you ?

Comment: i am trying to search a soution for my probelm but i couldn't do it i am new to stack over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your td is empty. Probe this:

```
<td> {{$payment->nameAttrib}} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mohamed, is there relation with student payment and student table.
if yes,
then write a relation student payment model

```
public function student(){
 return $this->belongsTo("App\Student","<student_id>")
}
```

In view

```
//student
@foreach($payment_s as $payment)
  <td>{{$payment->student-><colum_name>}}</td>//To print details from student table
  rest ur need
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Mohamed Midou <student_id> student_payment  table student's id